# Getting filename a exampe came from in tf,parse_exampes

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am writing a Data input pipeline in tensorflow that uses a bunch of tfrecord files with different Examples (types).

I am using code like:

```
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
```

However I want my parse_function to be different for file1.tfrecord than for file2.tfrecord. How do I achieve this. Is there someway of knowin in parse_example which file a particular example came from?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`Dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) transformation to include the filename with each record as follows:

```py
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
filenames = tf.data.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

# `Dataset.flat_map()` creates a nested dataset from each element in `filenames`.
#
# For each file in filename, zip together the filename (repeated infinitely) with
# the records read from that file.
dataset = filenames.flat_map(
    lambda fn: tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(fn).repeat(None),
                                    tf.data.TFRecordDataset(fn))))

# The _parse_function can now be modified to take both the filename and the record.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda fn, record: _parse_function(fn, record))
```